# laggy web page with jquery and images

Tags: google-chrome, profiling

I have a slow down problem with my single page website: basically it uses a LOT of memory (around 120MB) and, when scrolling, it can easily reach 40-90% of CPU usage! I am wondering what the problem might be so I will try to explain what resources I am using.

- 50 20kb sized images (stretched to around 200x200px)
- medium jQuery usage (some effects, a lot of AJAX)
- jQuery isotope plugin
- using hash change events to have sort of PiP (page in page) effects - like open a profile or a comment view -
- around 20 jQuery event listeners
- saving to localStorage every 10 seconds

Could this even be enough to slow it down that much, especially when scrolling? I am pretty sure there are much heavier pages like facebook, g docs, etc.

I have absolutely no problem with safari (I am on mac) but chrome gets really laggy. I cannot seem to find a profiler that can help me isolate the problem.

I have also removed all the effets regarding box-shadow or transparencies.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is a problem to be addressed to some issues regarding chrome ONLY on the new macbook retina displays, ad can be seen in this https://github.com/richardshepherd/Parallax-Scrolling/issues/6 or other threads. problem solved.

Comment: Glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

This sound very strange. When you say it uses a lot of memory I guess you are talking about RAM. It sounds like something is very badly wrong with the jquery code. If you are using a number of plugins something might be conflicting.

From the limited information you have provided it sounds like it is getting stuck in an infinite loop. If this page is already on the web and you provide a link I might be able to take a closer look.

Comment: Looking now at the site

Comment: thank you mate... really! i always knew you british are just the best.

Comment: I called myself John and then it asked me to register again and I chose Bob. I'm using Chrome and am not noticing any major issue. It isn't particularly fast but a lot is going on. I'm using Chrome on Windows at the moment. I'll try on my mac.